# Python: Why two global variables have different behaviours?

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, local-variables

I have a piece of code like this further down.

With this code I get a:

```
local variable 'commentsMade' referenced before assignment
```

Why do I need a 'global commentsMade' statement in the first function but I don't need with TARGET_LINES? (using Python2.7)

```
TARGET_LINE1 = r'someString'
TARGET_LINE2 = r'someString2'
TARGET_LINES = [TARGET_LINE1, TARGET_LINE2]
commentsMade = 2

def replaceLine(pattern, replacement, line, adding):

    #global commentsMade  # =========> Doesn't work. Uncommenting this does!!!!

    match = re.search(pattern, line)
    if match:
        line = re.sub(pattern, replacement, line)
        print 'Value before = %d ' % commentsMade
        commentsMade += adding
        print 'Value after = %d ' % commentsMade
    return line

def commentLine(pattern, line):
    lineToComment = r'(\s*)(' + pattern + r')(\s*)$'
    return replaceLine(lineToComment, r'\1<!--\2-->\3', line, +1)

def commentPomFile():
    with open('pom.xml', 'r+') as pomFile:
        lines = pomFile.readlines()
        pomFile.seek(0)
        pomFile.truncate()

        for line in lines:
            if commentsMade < 2:

                for targetLine in TARGET_LINES: # ===> Why this works???

                    line = commentLine(targetLine, line)

            pomFile.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    commentPomFile()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an assignment to a variable in the body of a function, then Python treats the variable as local (unless you declare it global).  If you just read the value within the body of a function, without assigning to it, then it looks for the variable in a higher scope (e.g., parent function or global).

So in your case, the difference is that you assign to `commentsMade`, which makes it local, but you don't assign to `TARGET_LINES`, so it looks for a global definition for it.